# Replacing text in HTML from async API calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, dom-traversal

I am calling an async function on all the HTML of a page 5000 characters at a time, and then want to replace the 5000 characters in place as I hear back from the API. However I am having trouble replacing the returned text in place.

Note that this is async, so they can come back in any order. The returned text should just 'pop-in' as the appropriate API function returns.

```
var textbody = document.body.innerHTML;
var loops = textbody.length/5000;
var translatedHTML = '';

for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var translatetext = document.body.innerHTML.substring(5000*i, (5000*i)+5000);
        //call an Async API to translatetext

       //callback for async API call
            {
                var translation = xmlhttp2.responseText;
                var refreshHTML = document.body.innerHTML;

                //WHAT AM I DOING HERE?! NEED TO REPLACE TEXT IN PLACE
                translatedHTML = refreshHTML.slice(5000*(i-1), 5000*i) + arraytrans + refreshHTML.slice(5000*i+5000); 
                document.body.innerHTML = translatedHTML;
            }   

    })(i);
}
```

});

**Update:** I tried linostar's approach and while it does replace the HTML as expected, it completely screws up the formatting of the page. Is there a different approach I should take instead?

```
(function (i) {
    var translatetext = document.body.innerHTML.substring(5000*i, (5000*i)+5000);
    //call an Async API to translatetext

    //callback for async API call
        {
        var translation = xmlhttp2.responseText;
        var refreshHTML = document.body.innerHTML;

        if (i == 0)
            translatedHTML = arraytrans + refreshHTML.substring(5000*i+5000);
        else if (i == loops - 1)
            translatedHTML = refreshHTML.substring(0, 5000*i) + arraytrans;
        else
            translatedHTML = refreshHTML.substring(0, 5000*i) + arraytrans + refreshHTML.substring(5000*i+5000);

        document.body.innerHTML = translatedHTML;
        }   
    })(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you isng `slice` function on refreshHTML? `slice` is used to cut portions from an array, and you are not using it on an array here.

Use the following instead:

```
if (i == 0)
  translatedHTML = arraytrans + refreshHTML.substring(5000*i+5000);
else if (i == loops - 1)
  translatedHTML = refreshHTML.substring(0, 5000*i) + arraytrans;
else
  translatedHTML = refreshHTML.substring(0, 5000*i) + arraytrans + refreshHTML.substring(5000*i+5000);
```

Comment: I tried this. So practically, this should work however I am seeing that it messes up the format of the page completely. It reorders all the elements and makes them jumbled up.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what other html content are you putting with your code. Paste all the relevent parts of your code where you add other html contents or change the innerHTML of your document's body.